# Enabling and disabling ActionButton dynamically in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing an application in RShiny. There is a complete button. It's ID is **"submit"**  The complete button should be enabled only when certain details are filled. Initially there are three Numeric Inputs. The ID's are **"current"**, **"next"**, **"next1"**.

The screenshot of Numeric Input is:

[image]

Following it, there are three selectize Inputs. The ID's are **"sel1"**, **"sel2"**, **"sel3"**.

The screenshot of Selectize Input is:

[image]

Later, there are three textOutputs. The ID's are **"text2"**, **"text3"**, **"text4"**. It should be 100%. To obtain 100%,  3 **"reactive()"** are used.

This is the RCode used.

```
    require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")
ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center', '.form-control' = 'padding:8.5px ')),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  ),
                  column(3, actionButton("submit", "Complete"))
                ),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,tags$h3("Actual Work Hours")
                  ),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    numericInput("current", "Current Week",value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
                  )),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    numericInput("next1", "Next Week", value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
                  )),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    numericInput("next2", "Two weeks from now", value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
                  ))),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,tags$h3("About Your Work-Week")
                  ),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    selectizeInput("sel1", "How was your current week?",
                                   choices = c("aa",
                                               "bb",
                                               "cc"),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = "Current week",
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                   )))),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    selectizeInput("sel2", "How busy will be the next week?",
                                   choices = c("aa",
                                               "bb",
                                               "cc"),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = "Next week",
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                   )))),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    selectizeInput("sel3", "How busy will be the next two weeks?",
                                   choices = c("aa",
                                               "bb",
                                               "cc"),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = "Next two week",
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                   ))))),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3")),
                                tags$head(tags$style("#text3{color: white;
                                                     font-style: italic;
                                                     }"
                         )
                                )))
)
# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                              column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)
  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})
  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })
  output$text3 <- renderText({
    getvalues()
  })
  observeEvent(getvalues(), {
    nn <- getvalues()
    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      removeClass("text3", 'red')
      addClass('text3','lightpink')

    } else  { addClass('text3','red')}
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

The above code does not produce desired output. In short, the Complete button should be enabled only when Numeric Input, Selectize Input are filled and textOutput should be 100%. Can anyone provide a solution for this issue?

Comment: You can try using `shinyjs` hide/show option.

Comment: Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: I have posted it. Please take a look at it

Comment: I am a bit confused, so if the number is 100 when it turns pink, then submit button should come?

Comment: Yeah. The numeric Input, selectize Input should be filled and textOutput should be exactly 100. If so, Complete button should be enabled. Else it should be disabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180395/can-you-use-shinyjs-to-hide-show-whole-panels

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar Check the answer if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code with `disable` and `enable` of `shinyjs` and also to account the condition of work week selection.

```
 require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")
ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink", ".hide1"="display:none",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center', '.form-control' = 'padding:8.5px ')),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  ),
                  column(3, actionButton("submit", "Complete")) 

                ),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,tags$h3("Actual Work Hours")
                  ),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    numericInput("current", "Current Week",value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
                  )),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    numericInput("next1", "Next Week", value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
                  )),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    numericInput("next2", "Two weeks from now", value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
                  ))),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,tags$h3("About Your Work-Week")
                  ),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    selectizeInput("sel1", "How was your current week?",
                                   choices = c("aa",
                                               "bb",
                                               "cc"),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = "Current week",
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                   )))),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    selectizeInput("sel2", "How busy will be the next week?",
                                   choices = c("aa",
                                               "bb",
                                               "cc"),
                                   selected = NULL,
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = "Next week",
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                   )))),
                  column(3, wellPanel(
                    selectizeInput("sel3", "How busy will be the next two weeks?",
                                   choices = c("aa",
                                               "bb",
                                               "cc"),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = "Next two week",
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                                   ))))),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3")),
                                tags$head(tags$style("#text3{color: white;
                                                     font-style: italic;
                                                     }"
                         )
                                )))
                                )
# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                               column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)
  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})
  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })
  output$text3 <- renderText({
    getvalues()
  })
  observeEvent(getvalues(), {
    nn <- getvalues()
    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      removeClass("text3", 'red')
      addClass('text3','lightpink')
      if(input$sel1 != "" & input$sel2 != "" & input$sel3 != "") {

        enable('submit')  
      }

      #removeClass('submit','hide1')


    } else  { addClass('text3','red'); #addClass('submit','hide1');
      disable('submit')
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there any way to disable it rather than hiding? Also the Selectize input should be Selected. If not, the button should be disabled. Is it possible?

Comment: Updated the disable part. Please check.

Comment: Even if the work-week is not selected it enables the button.. Any solution for it?

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar Updated the answer to account work week selection.

Comment: Consider the following scenario. There are three reactive functions for 3 textOutput. Each reactive () holds the code for displaying some values in textOutput. Is there any way to enable the Submit button when the three textOutput holds the value of 100 individually?

Comment: You can definitely play around with the code that I have sent. All that will have to be changed is the `if` condition

Comment: How to access the value in textOutput?

Comment: Remember how we added pink to it? That's how it is.

Comment: `if(input$sel1 != "" & input$sel2 != "" & input$sel3 != "" & 'text2' == 100 & 'text3' == 100 & 'text4' == 100) {
        enable("submit")
      }  else{
        disable("submit")
      }`        Is this correct way?

Comment: But wait, how, if you have text1, tex2, text3 all equal to 100, then how come the sum be 100?

Comment: text1, text2 and text3 are 3 in columns. For instance , text1 holds the sum of values entered in TextAreaInputs which are present in first column. Similarly  the same from text2 and text3

Comment: That's fine, but you already have a condition checking if the sum is equal to 100 then only it should be displayed right? so if text1 and text2 are 100 then the sum would become 200 invalidating the condition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442890/locating-the-textareainput-side-by-side3-columns-at-required-position-using-r/46444746?noredirect=1#comment80555582_46444746           Similar to this

Comment: Since there are 3 textOutput, each textOutput should hold 100. And the button should be enabled only if the 3 textOutput holds the value of 100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159571/discussion-between-amrrs-and-nevedha-ayyanar).